# Spring - How to secure Server Sent Events

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, jwt

I want to to use Springs Server Sent Events to update specific parts in a Angular frontend. I want that only authorized user can subscribe to the Server Sent Events. That's not the problem but how can I check if the user is still authorized to retrieve the push messages after e.g. the session is expired?

I'm also using JWT Token based authorisation so that the server doesn't know when the token expires. What is a good practice here? Should I save the token alongside with the SseEmitter and check it before each push?

Thanks!